# Invoke JS method directly from CasperJS

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to test a page using CasperJS, in particular I want to poke the data model a bunch. Let's say I've got a basic function called taxes, and I want to ensure that it uses the right tax rate. So I'd like something like:

```
 this.test.assert(taxes(100, 'Ontario') === 15, "Check ontario tax rate");
```

Rather than filling out a form and seeing what it prints. That `taxes` method exists in the global scope, so I'm able to execute it quite easily from anywhere (including from the console in firebug or Chrome). But it's not in the right scope for that to work inside CasperJS (I think? I'm getting `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: taxes`.

It seems like I'm missing something simple.

TL;DR: How do I execute an on-page bit of JS directly inside a CasperJS test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using [`evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)?

relevant quote: "execute code as if you were using the browser console."

something along the lines of:

```
casper.evaluate(function(amount, province) {

    return taxes(amount, province);

}, {100, 'Ontario'});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed that note, I think I was using "scope" as a keyword search on the page and came up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [assertEvalEquals()](http://casperjs.org/api.html#tester.assertEvalEquals) method.

Comment: While this theoretically does answer the question, if the link breaks - so does the context of this answer. Can you show _how_ to use the method in this answer, so it remains useful even if the link can't be resolved? It will probably be removed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the method via a jQuery-style reference, make sure to explicitly include the library, lest you'll get the ReferenceError:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({ 
   clientScripts: ['js/jquery-1.7.2.js'] 
});
```

...

```
casper.start('foo.php', 
   function() { 
      console.log(this.evaluate(function() { 
         return $('taxes').text(); 
      }));
   }); 

casper.run();
```

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/casperjs/2uyUOqdzShw/bHWrJYXni40J

If you're calling it implicitly in the global scope (i.e., straight javascript, rather than, for example, $('taxes')), you might have to explicitly prepend the window or document namespace to the reference:

```
document.querySelector('#taxes').value = taxes_text;
```